# Boot menu is stopping after selecting media in inst.dd command

Tags: boot, installation, centos-7, modprobe

I'm trying to install CentOS7 into HP Microserver ProLient G8. I need to disable AHCI and change array driver as the following site describes.

http://josafatisai.blogspot.com/2016/01/installing-centos-7-on-hp-proliant.html

I did the following command from boot prompt.

```
linux modprobe.blacklist=ahci inst.dd
```

and selected the number for the driver media of `kmod-hpvsa-1.2.16-102.rhel7u3.x86_64.rpm`

Then pressed 'c' to continue after I confirmed the toggle was selected as 'x' `forkmod-hpvsa-1.2.16-102.rhel7u3.x86_64.rpm`.

However, nothing is happen even showing error message.

It seems stopping or waiting something.

Does anyone tell how to continue the boot menu or how to check the system.

My installer is version 7.8.2003 `CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-2003.iso`

Additional information.

I also tried `CentOS6.7.x86_64-minimal.iso` with driver `hpva-1.2.8-140.rhel6ux86.dd` by following instruction.

https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c03582943-1

There was an error below.

```
                  |Error|
No new drivers were fond on this driver disk. This may    
Indicate that this disk has already been loaded or that     
the drivers it contains don't match your hardware. Would     
you like to manually select the driver, continue anyway,    
or load another driver disk? 
|Manually choose|     |Continue|    |Load another disk|
```

If I press `Continue` ,installation began and soon show following message.

```
           |No driver found|
Unable to find any drivers of the type
needed for this installation type.
Would you like to manually select your
driver or use a driver disk?
|Select driver| |Use a driver disk| |back|
```

Then went back to  `No new drivers were fond` messages and repeating.

I found a specific combination that can install.

It was the combination with`CentOS-6.9-x86_64-minimal.iso` and `hpvsa-1.2.16-122.rhel6u9.x86_64.dd.gz`

However, I'd like to install CentOC7.

Since I don't have enough time, i decided to upgrade from CentoOS6 to CentOS7.

I get the combination which I can install and change the driver.

It's `CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso` and `hpvsa-1.2.16-102.rhel7u1.x86_64.dd` .

Comment: Off-topic cross-site duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020451/boot-menu-is-stopping-after-selecting-media-in-inst-dd-command (closed) https://serverfault.com/questions/1034983/boot-menu-is-stopping-after-selecting-media-in-inst-dd-command (not yet)

Comment: i deleted the post from serverfault.

Comment: Try drivers listed [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_4316d9b65662412686bc826572#tab4).

Comment: Already tried as I posted. hpvsa-1.2.16-102****.dd.gz in your link includes `kmod-hpvsa-1.2.16-102.rhel7u3.x86_64.rpm`  in my post. But thanks anyway

Comment: @Ankit Write your solution as the answer. You are information worked.

Comment: @user1345414 Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combination of driver and CentOS 7 which works on HP Microserver ProLiant G8 is `CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso` and `hpvsa-1.2.16-102.rhel7u1.x86_64.dd`
Drivers can be downloaded from this [website](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_4316d9b65662412686bc826572).